# Usage analysis problem - wss

Tags: wss-3.0, site-usage

I have enabled usage analysis processing and logging on my wss central admin site and the status from the stsadm command is showing  which means that it is enabled.

I can also see the logs are saved in the logs folder but when I am trying to see the report on the site by going to usagedetail.aspx page it says "usage report is disabled for this site"

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Verify your log directory is available on each server if you have multiple servers. Also be sure the ASP.NET State Service is running.

Comment: I cannot see this feature in the site collection features list

Comment: I have to apologize, I sent you on a wild goose chase, the "Reports" feature will only be available if you are running MOSS.  I've edited the reply.